# WCF error - Cannot receive the MessageHeaders added at the Client side

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to use this simple code in WCF:

Client Side:

```
ServiceContractClient proxy = new ServiceContractClient();
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)proxy.InnerChannel))
        {
            MessageHeaders messageHeadersElement = OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders;
            messageHeadersElement.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("username", String.Empty, System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name)); 
        }
var res = proxy.CallWCFMethod();
```

Server Side:

The CallWCFMethod implements another method, GetInfo(). The code for GetInfo() is :

```
MessageHeaders messageHeadersElement = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;            
        int AdidIndex = messageHeadersElement.FindHeader("username", string.Empty);
        string ticket = messageHeadersElement.GetHeader<string>("username", string.Empty);
```

But this code can never find the Header "username" I added in the client. Can someone point out to me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [`OperationContextScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontextscope.aspx) is scoped too small. Put the closing brace *after* the `proxy.CallWCFMethod()` and it should work:

```
ServiceContractClient proxy = new ServiceContractClient();
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)proxy.InnerChannel))
{
    MessageHeaders messageHeadersElement = OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders;
    messageHeadersElement.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("username", String.Empty,
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name)); 
    var res = proxy.CallWCFMethod();
}
```

You will probably have to refactor your code some more, because you will want to declare your `res` variable outside the `using` scope. You will have to explicitly type the variable in such a case.